# Database for electron app

Tags: electron

Recently started with electron. Can any one please help me with the database selection. It seems like there is no straight forward choice for it.
Suggest a database for medium size project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Electron app, you can use the database of your choice :

https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb

http://lokijs.org

https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb

https://github.com/amark/gun

https://github.com/typicode/lowdb

https://github.com/google/leveldb

According to your purpose, a single JSON file can be used as a database.

Comment: Are they reliable like MySQL or mongod b ?

Comment: Those databases are for a standalone use in the Electron app. To connect to a MySQL database, you can use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql and for mongodb : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), which is the non-sql database, in that you can store data in JSON format, they have inbuilt sync functionality, that means, you just need to store data locally in HTML storage provider and CouchDB will automatically sync that with the server.